# Using generics to map interface types to classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have several `Get____Factory` methods in my application and I'd like to consolidate them with generics, but I'm still adjusting C# and a) am not 100% sure generics are the right way to go and b) am still learning how C# handles generics.

I'll eventually have a dictionary/map of factory interfaces and their classes. Not only do I want to consolidate all of my factories into an easy-access method but I need to allow plugin authors a way to register their own (and have access to them this way).

I started with something like this:

**Note:** Eventually there will be a dictionary or way to map interfaces types to their implementations - the if/else conditions are ugly and temporary, but simply a way to test.

```
public T GetFactory<T>() where T : IFactory {
    var t = typeof(T);

    if (t.Equals(typeof(IRecipeFactory))) {
        var factory = new RecipeFactory();
        return factory;
    }

    else if (t.Equals(typeof(IItemFactory))) {
        var factory = new ItemFactory();
        return factory;
    }

    else if (t.Equals(typeof(ITileFactory))) {
        var factory = new TileFactory();
        return factory;
    }
}
```

It fails with `Cannot implicitly convert type 'RecipeFactory' to 'T'`, so this won't work. In the long run I won't have conditionals but will rather lookup the class by its type. However, neither will work until I can find a solution for the cast issue.

Based on other answers, I tried double-casting (`(T) (object)`) but that errors with `InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.`.

Either this is a poor architecture or I'm using the generics incorrectly.

Comment: why do you want to return a generic type but then you have an object of a specific type in the return statement ?!!

Comment: I suppose if you put 2 or more examples of `Get___Factory` methods you have then maybe we can help

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I want to provide a mapping of factory interfaces to their instances. I may wind up with a dozen SomethingFactory classes. The method is exposed to plugins which don't have direct access to the implementations, only the interfaces. I'll add more examples

Comment: hmm if you change `var` into `IFactory` and then `return (T)factory;` then it will work and no exception will raise if you were careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to cast the object to `T` on the way out since the method returns `T`. To do this cast you will have to make `factory` an `IFactory`

```
public T GetFactory<T>() where T : IFactory
{
    var t = typeof(T);

    if (t.Equals(typeof(IRecipeFactory)))
    {
        IFactory factory = new RecipeFactory();
        return (T)factory;
    }

    if (t.Equals(typeof(IItemFactory)))
    {
        IFactory factory = new ItemFactory();
        return (T)factory;
    }

    if (t.Equals(typeof(ITileFactory)))
    {
        IFactory factory = new TileFactory();
        return (T)factory;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Type not supported");
}
```

Comment: I tried this early on, and it failed, but I failed to realize it failed due to different errors, not because I was casting incorrectly.

Comment: This is functional but has a ton of redundant code and needs a specific case for every single type that is added, which is definitely not going to work (at least not elegantly) if plugin creation is opened up to the general community. I understand this is just a fixed version of OP's code, but see my answer for a more appropriate approach.

Comment: You are correct. The approach that the OP is using might not be the "best" way to do it. However, the OP's question was not how to do it better, it was how to make the approach being used work. Going outside that scope would be best left for another question as it is a completely different topic.

Comment: Agreed and understood, but it's not necessarily a different topic. OP mentions the possibility of bad architecture or improper use of generics. I think your approach is a working version of what he was tried while mine is a working version of what he had in mind. Just two sides of the same coin.

Comment: I would suggest using the concrete interface type instead of `IFactory` when creating the factory instance. E.g. `if (t == typeof(IItemFactory)) { IItemFactory factory = new ItemFactory(); return factory; }` So that no casting is needed.

Comment: Plus, I did acknowledge the hard-coded conditions were temporary. A more dynamic system is the next step so I will certainly read through the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution bit different from S.C.'s solution.

```
public static class FactoryService
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<IFactory>> factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IFactory>>()
    {
        { typeof(IRecipeFactory), () => new RecipeFactory() },
        { typeof(IItemFactory), () => new ItemFactory() },
        { typeof(ITileFactory), () => new TileFactory() }
    };

    public static T GetFactory<T>() where T : IFactory
    {
        T factory = default(T);
        Type requestedType = typeof(T);

        if (factories.ContainsKey(requestedType))
        {
            factory = (T)factories[requestedType].Invoke();
        }

        return factory;
    }
}

public interface IFactory { }

public interface IRecipeFactory : IFactory { }

public interface IItemFactory : IFactory { }

public interface ITileFactory : IFactory { }

public class RecipeFactory : IRecipeFactory { }

public class ItemFactory : IItemFactory { }

public class TileFactory : ITileFactory { }
```

Then you use it like this:

```
IRecipeFactory rf = FactoryService.GetFactory<IRecipeFactory>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me first say that you are actually looking at is a simple version of an Inversion of Control (IOC) framework. Take a look at [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) or something similar because it's kernel and binding factory are pretty much exactly what you want. It even allows the attachment of metadata so you can have the same interface resolve to different implementations depending on the circumstances, which is really useful when you have a data layer that might need to pull from either a web data source or a cache data source, for instance. Most IOC frameworks also offer recursive dependency resolution, which means when some instances have constructors that require other dependencies, the same dependency resolution occurs all the way down the chain based on the mappings or default mappings that can be inferred.

Aside from that, to do what you're after yourself, you'll want to make use of `Activator.CreateInstance` which takes a type and will construct a new instance based on that. You are on the right track with your dictionary mappings. When you tie those two together, you don't need any conditional logic and you don't need to know ahead of time or care about what type is being requested. When you're feeling comfortable you can actually shorten the dependency resolution and instantiation to a single line if you wish.

Here is a fully working sample (from my 30 seconds of testing) that does what you want to to the best of my understanding:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Generics
{
    // create some dummy interfaces and implementations. 
    // make sure everything inherits from the same type to allow for 
    // a generic return statement
    public interface IFactory
    {
        void DoStuff();
    }
    public interface IFactory1 : IFactory { }
    public class Factory1 : IFactory1
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Factory1");
        }
    }
    public interface IFactory2 : IFactory { }
    public class Factory2 : IFactory2
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Factory2");
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        // create our binding mappings
        IDictionary<Type, Type> bindings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
            {
                // expose a way for plugins/etc to add to this. that part is trivial.
                {typeof(IFactory1), typeof(Factory1) },
                {typeof(IFactory2), typeof(Factory2) }
            };

        // a method to actually resolve bindings based on expected types
        public IFactory ResolveBinding<T>() where T : IFactory
        {
            Type requestedType = typeof(T);
            if (requestedType != null && bindings.ContainsKey(requestedType))
            {
                // use the activator to generically create an instance
                return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(bindings[requestedType]);
            }

            return null;
        }

        // test it out
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program demo = new Program();
            // test with two interfaces
            demo.ResolveBinding<IFactory1>().DoStuff(); // prints out "Factory1"
            demo.ResolveBinding<IFactory2>().DoStuff(); // prints out "Factory2"
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```